# How to create class with comparator?

Tags: c++

How do I create a class that takes a comparator template like `std::less<T>` or `std::equal_to<T>` like `std::multiset` and `std::set` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

```
template <class T, class Comparator = std::less<T>>
class MyClass
{
  bool compare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const { return Comparator()(lhs, rhs); }
  // stuff
};

class A
{
public:
    bool operator < (const A& rhs) const;
};

MyClass<A> myClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T, class Comparator = std::less<T>>
class MyClass
{
  //...
}
```

In member function, something like :-

```
void MyClass::Myfun(X x, Comparator mycomp = Comparator())
{

  if (mycomp(data1,data2)) 
    //...

}
```

Comment: No, I want to create a class that takes **this** as a template parameter

Answer (score 0):

The STL containers actually store an instance of the comparator, so what you want is closer to this:

```
template <class T, class Comparator = std::less<T>>
class MyClass : private Comparator
{
public:
    MyClass() {}
    MyClass( const Comparator& compare ) : Comparator( compare ) {}

    bool compare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const
    {
        return static_cast<Comparator>(*this)(lhs, rhs);
    }

    // stuff
};

class A
{
public:
    bool operator < (const A& rhs) const;
};

MyClass<A> myClass;
```

Note that you should use private inheritance to allow the empty base optimization to remove overhead in case the `Comparator` does not contain any state.